# How do you model a shape that is asymmetrical?

Tags: modeling

I really like this shape but I cant seem to even begin modelling this. Any tips? Is sculpting a good idea?

[image]

Comment: modeling will be much easier, use your image as a Reference

Answer (score 2):

in your 3D view, *Add > Image > Reference >* select your image, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reset its rotation, choose orthographic top view, create a plane and extrude until you have this kind of result:

[image]

Then extrude up, bevel the angle, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, etc...

Comment: Will try this, thank you!

Comment: If you ever meet difficulties, please ask here  ;)